# Scroll effect for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using horizontal RecyclerView in Android app.
Showing two items (ImageViews) on the screen at a time.

To do this I am setting the width of each ImageView to half of the screen in ViewHolder class of the adapter:

```
  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { 

  private LinearLayout ll_Img;
        private ImageView iv_ad;


        private ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            ll_Img = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_Img);
            ll_Img.getLayoutParams().width = (Utils.getScreenWidth(itemView.getContext()) / 2);

            iv_ad = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_main_ad);
        }
    }
```

And getting screen's width:

```
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;

    return screenWidth;
}
```

It works fine but I want to implement scroll effect like on iOS,
to scroll one item per swipe,
so after each swipe 2 items must fit the screen width.

By the way, two videos worth 1000 words
so here what I am having now:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7j1Rf_oUEbLOWk1OUtpWXFpcEE/view?usp=sharing

And what I want to achieve (as my colleague implemented on iOS): 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6B-4-ITg1EQTElNTWsxMWg4aWs/view?usp=sharing

Each piece of advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is a viewpager, not a recyclerview. This link might help https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: Thank you. Very useful information

Comment: @billynomates, thanks once again. I achieved exactly what I wanted with this info. You can write an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a viewpager, not a recyclerview. This link might help https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Just for anyone else's benefit:

> `getPageWidth()` returns a floating-point number, between 0 and 1,
>   representing the portion of the width of the ViewPager that a given
>   page should take up. By default, the page width is 1, but by
>   overriding this, you can have multiple pages on the screen
>   simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this would give the desired effect, but if you are using a linearlayoutmanager, you could add a scrolllistener to your recyclerview, and whenever it gets called, use the linearlayout's method scrollToPosition to force it to scroll all the way to the next item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented desired with using of ViewPager